# mongo-express admin issue when using docker compose up

Tags: mongodb, mongo-express

I'm working on a task where I need to run mongo-express to show a website. Upon running docker-compose up, I am presented with an admin error. please see the images below of both the docker-compose.yml file and a screenshot of the error. Any help would be great.

How am i able to resolve this issue.

[image: docker-compose.yml]

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: `Authentication failed` - are you using the right credentials?

Comment: it should be just for a generic admin account where anyone can access it